# On error, show blank and resume to next row VBA MACRO

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple division for a range.

But on error, it should be: if cell D is empty, then E should also be empty.
I have tried lens and iferror or isblank and can't seem to get it to work.

[image]

```
Sub MyMacro()

Range("E9:E20").Formula = ("=1/D9")
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the formula you are looking for is `=IFERROR(1/D9,"")`

This will execute and return the division, but if the result is any error (because D9 is empty or doesn't contain a number), it will return an empty string. Of course you can replace that with any value you want.

If you want to write that via VBA, it is often easier to change to R1C1-Notation: `=IFERROR(1/RC[-1],"")`

```
With ActiveSheet    ' Replace this when you want to work on a specific sheet
    Dim formula As String
    formula = "=IFERROR(1/RC[-1],"""")" 
    .Range("E9:E20").FormulaR1C1 = formula
End With
```

**Update** (after clarifying what is needed).
Have a look to the following code. You will for sure need to handle the user input using the `Worksheet_Change`-Event. The code has 2 pieces:

If something was entered in the first column, the cell to the right will get the formula - but only if it doesn't contain a fixed value.

If a value on the second column was removed, it will get the formula again. Just adapt the ranges in the two `Intersect`-commands to your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const formula = "=IFERROR(1/RC[-1],"""")"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Change_Exit
    
    ' Handle first column
    Dim r As Range, cell As Range
    Set r = Intersect(Target, Range("D:D"))

    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In r
            Dim neighbor As Range
            Set neighbor = cell.Offset(0, 1)
            If neighbor.HasFormula Or IsEmpty(neighbor) Then
                Dim f As String
                neighbor.FormulaR1C1 = formula
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    
    ' Handle second column
    Set r = Intersect(Target, Range("E:E"))
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In r
            If IsEmpty(cell) Then    ' Value was deleted, write formula
                cell.FormulaR1C1 = formula
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
Change_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @funThomas. This has the same unforeseen issue as my code below. 

Person should be able to manually enter a number into Column D OR E. 

If someone enters values in D, then Column E gets a formula. 
If they enter into Column E, column D will always be blank. No formula. 

To make this simple. I can upload a test sheet of current formula so you can see what I mean.

Comment: here is a sample sheet for you with the steps numbered to discover the same error I am getting. https://veritiv.box.com/s/zsfnrtjroxa68dzvvsrfvphjd041r2jj

Comment: Sorry, not offense, but most people don't want to download and open Macro-Enabled Excel files from an unknown source. And I am one of them...

Comment: sorry I didn't know! Would it work if I sent regular excel, then just told you what VBA I put? Not sure what best practice is for sharing examples, so please let me know what you prefer / if any.

Comment: I think you should simply explain what you try to achieve. As far as I understand: If user enters a number in col D, the cell to the left should have the value `1/RC[-1]`. If user enters something in col E, the cell to the right should be empty.

Comment: Okay I can try to explain. Just in case: Normal Excel File. https://veritiv.box.com/s/kbnviuyrg5lai3kq79mpuiuakwnv6p8y 

This is VBA code I put: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D9:D20")) Is Nothing Then
Call MyMacro
End If
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
With ActiveSheet    ' Replace this when you want to work on a specific sheet
    Dim formula As String
    
    formula = "=IFERROR(1/RC[-2],"""")"
    .Range("F9:F20").FormulaR1C1 = formula
End With
End Sub

Comment: So, from left to right, a person would only fill out certain cells in column D (conditionally formatted). If they fill this out, the cell to the right will have a formula added via VBA. 

Next, any blank values not filled out in column D, the person would fill out numbers into column E blank cells (no formula needed). 

The vba codes you or I worked on work fine up until this point. The issue is when, if anyone goes back and enters a new number in any cell in column D, it wipes all manually entered cells in column E.

Comment: THANK YOU! Works perfectly now. I didn't anticipate the issue initially, and I see how you handled it in two parts.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the above comment but figured it out partially.
Search for a specific error to clear, and set that error to "".

Then I created a private macro to run the main macro every time there is a cell change, so blank cells can now have the formula added back in after initial error clear.

Note: you must put this into the specific sheet, or add in worksheet targets if you want this in a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("P15:P134")) Is Nothing Then
Call MyMacro
End If
End Sub

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    Range("R15:R134").Formula = ("=1/P15")
    
            For Each Cell In Range("R15:R134")
                If IsError(Cell.Value) Then If Cell.Value = CVErr(xlErrDiv0) Then Cell.Value = ""
            Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. The above works, but if you change a lower cell, it overwrites the above cells and sets them back to 0.